# Demonstration with inequalities

Tags: inequality

I have these stated inequalities, true for all $i$.

$$\begin{align}
|P_{i}+q_{i}|\leq \epsilon \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

with $\epsilon > 0$ and I know that
$$\begin{align}
|P_{i}-P_{j}|\leq \delta \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

My problem is that by using (1) I want to show that (2) can be re-written in

$$|q_j-q_i|-2\epsilon \leq \delta$$

with $\delta > 0$. But I can't... I'm always blocked at the first step.

$$\begin{align}
|P_{i}-P_{j}|&\leq \delta \\
||P_{i}+q_i-q_i|-|P_{j}+q_j-q_j||&\leq \delta \\
?? |||P_{i}+q_i|-|q_i||-||P_{j}+q_j|-|q_j|||&\leq \delta \quad??\\
\end{align}$$

or

$$\begin{align}
|P_{i}-P_{j}|&\leq \delta \\
|(P_{i}+q_i)-(P_{j}+q_j)+(q_j-q_i)|&\leq \delta \\
\end{align}$$

but then what ? Since $-\epsilon\leq(P_{i}+q_i) \leq \epsilon$, can I simply say that the expression here $(P_{i}+q_i)-(P_{j}+q_j)$ is at maximum $2\epsilon$ and minimum $-2\epsilon$ and that that implies that the result is evident ?

I'm not able to go further... I only used these triangular inequalities
$$\begin{align}
|x+y|&\leq |x|+|y| \\
|x-y|&\geq ||x|-|y||
\end{align}$$
to get to my result. Should I use some other things because I don't see anything? Is the fact that both $-1\leq P_i\leq 1$ and $-1\leq q_i \leq 1$ an important fact I could use ? Or maybe it's impossible to prove it?

Comment: Hint: Use the reverse triangle inequality, i.e. $|x-y|\geq\bigg||x|-|y|\bigg|$, to show that
$\bigg||q_j-q_i|-|P_i+q_i|-|P_j+q_j|\bigg|\leq|(P_i+q_i)-(P_j+q_j)+(q_j-q_i)|.$

Comment: @User84559 Wait, how ? 
$\left|(q_j-q_i)-(P_j+q_j)-(-(P_i+q_i))\right| \leq \left||q_j-q_i|-|P_j+q_j|-\left|-(P_i+q_i)\right|\right|$, the latter being equal to the lefthand side in your comment ?

Comment: The inequality I posted is not correct; I apologize. It should be
$$|q_j-q_i|-|P_i+q_i|-|P_j+q_j|\leq|(P_i+q_i)-(P_j+q_j)+(q_j-q_i)|.$$
Rick Decker's answer is more direct, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.
$$
\begin{align}
|q_i-q_j| &= |P_i+P_j-P_i-P_j+q_i-q_j|\\
 &=|(P_i+q_i)+(-P_j-q_j)+(P_j-P_i)|\\
 &\le |P_i+q_i|+|-(P_j+q_j)|+|P_j-P_i|\\
 &\le \epsilon +\epsilon+\delta
\end{align}
$$